# Read log files from back to top - perl

Tags: perl, glob

I try to read log files from array from back to top but when log is closed it finish with follow error after `close($bw);`:

```
Not a GLOB reference at script.pl line 171.
  at /script.pl line 171.
  main::process_log("file.log") called at script.pl line 179
```

Part of the script where issue appear:

```
for my $file (@logs){
  process_log $file;
}

sub process_log {
  my $bw;

  $bw = File::ReadBackwards->new( $file ) or die "can't read $file $!" ;
  my $filename = 'status.log';
        open(FW, '>', $filename) or die $!;
        print FW "Processing file: $file\n";
        close(FW);

  $file =~ m"$logdir/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+\-*\w*\-*\w*)/(.*\.log)$";

  my $cmppattern = "${date}T${hour}";
  my $row;

  while( defined( $row = $bw->readline ) ) {
    if ( $row =~ m/^$cmppattern/ ) {
   
#DO SOMETHING
   
     last if ( $nlines > 0 && $row !~ m/^$cmppattern/ )
  }
  close($bw);
}
```

Comment: Really needs a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$bw is an object, not a file handle. So you need to close using a method call:

```
$bw->close();
```